# Adding form elements dynamically to Bootstrap multiselect library

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the Bootstrap multiselect library (http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started ) to use form controls, namely checkboxes in a Bootstrap dropdown. I am trying to populate options dynamically as opposed to the example. However, adding elements dynamically causes the dropdown to close immediately after selecting a form element (perhaps this has to do with event propagation) and does not allow me to manipulate other checkboxes. How do I resolve this issue ?

Specifically how do I populate elements dynamically into the **select** tag ? The example:

```
 <select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
    <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
    <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
    <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: If you're populating the select AFTER you initialize the multiselect it probably can't recognize the items. Try loading the items into the select and then initializing the multiselect on it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#example-getting-started').append($('<option>', {
      value: 'optionValue',
      text : 'optionText'
    }));
```

then:

```
$('#example-getting-started').multiselect('rebuild');
```