# Bootstrap multiselect not populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a bootstrap multiselect dropdown box which gets populated through AJAX. While I am getting the value from the AJAX I am not able to populate the multiselect dropdown. I have another normal dropdown which uses the same AJAX function and it gets populated. Am I missing something?

I did check this link which did not work for me [Adding form elements dynamically to Bootstrap multiselect library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884824/adding-form-elements-dynamically-to-bootstrap-multiselect-library)

This is the HTML

```
var lstValue = "";
<select id='sellstValue" + obj.id + "' class='lstvalue' hidden='hidden'>" + lstValue + "</select>
```

This is my AJAX code

```
var lstvalue = $('#' + rowId).find('.lstvalue').prop('id');
$.ajax({
          cache: false,
          url: '@Url.Action("PopulateDropdown", "AdvancedSearch")',
          type: "POST",
          data: { Field: field }
            }).done(function (data) {
           console.log(data.value)
           var listb = $('#' + lstvalue);
           listb.empty();

           $.each(data.value, function (index, value) {
           listb.append($('<option>', {
                 value: value,
                 text: value
                  }, '<option/>'))
                });
            console.log($('#' + lstvalue))
            });

            $('#' + lstvalue).attr('multiple', 'multiple');
            $('#' + lstvalue).multiselect();
```

I checked the console output of console.log($('#' + lstvalue)) which gives me the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why this worked but adding 'async: false' in my AJAX call helped solve it.

Comment: You are not triggering actions on the success callback, and AJAX's nature is to execute asynchronously so you usually concatenate actions on the success callback or the .done method, helpful because you can also show errors when the AJAX transaction fails.

Comment: the multiselect() can't put in the loop, it's a synchronize function that causes handler events.